# JavaScript regex to get first character of each word in a sentence (Persian, and English sentence)

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have the following string:

```
var englishSentence = 'Hellow World';
var persianSentence = 'گروه جوانان خلاق';
```

For english I use from following regex, but how can I write a regex to support Persian, or mix of them.

```
  var matches = englishSentence.match(/\b(\w)/g);
  acronym = matches.join('');
```

Comment: How should the output look like?

Comment: try `sentence.split( /\s+/ ).map( s => s.charAt(0) )`

Comment: For Persian it should be گجخ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Root cause

There is no way to match a Unicode word boundary, `\b` is not Unicode aware even in ECMA 2018.

## Solutions

For ECMA2018 compatible browsers (e.g. the latest versions of Chrome as of April 2018) you may use:

```js
var englishSentence = 'Hellow World';
var persianSentence = 'گروه جوانان خلاق';
var reg = /(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*)\p{L}\p{M}*/gu;
console.log(englishSentence.match(reg));
console.log(persianSentence.match(reg));
```

**Details**

- `(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a Unicode letter followed with 0+ diacritics
- `\p{L}\p{M}*` - a Unicode letter followed with 0+ diacritics
- `gu` - `g` - global, search for all matches, `u` - make the pattern Unicode aware.

If you need the same functionality in older/other browsers, use `XRegExp`:

```js
function getFirstLetters(s, regex) {
  var results=[], match;
  XRegExp.forEach(s, regex, function (match, i) {
    results.push(match[1]);
  });
  return results;
}
var rx = XRegExp("(?:^|[^\\pL\\pM])(\\pL\\pM*)", "gu");
console.log(getFirstLetters("Hello world", rx));
console.log(getFirstLetters('گروه جوانان خلاق', rx));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.js"></script>
```

**Details**

- `(?:^|[^\\pL\\pM])` - a non-capturing group that matches the start of the string (`^`) or any char other than a Unicode letter or diacritic
- `(\\pL\\pM*)` - Group 1: any Unicode letter followed with 0+ diacritics.

Here, we need to extract Group 1 value, hence `.push(match[1])` upon each match.

Comment: No, I need it for older versions.

Comment: @jones You should import an extra library to your project (>200kb in size) and `\pL` accepts all letters from all languages not just Persian and English.

Answer (score 1):

You can split by space(s) and then get the first character of each item

```
var output = sentence.split( /\s+/ ).map( s => s.charAt(0) ).join("")
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnGetFirstChar = (sentence) => sentence.split( /\s+/ ).map( s => s.charAt(0) ).join("");

var englishSentence = 'Hellow World';
var persianSentence = 'گروه جوانان خلاق';

console.log( fnGetFirstChar( englishSentence ) );

console.log( fnGetFirstChar( persianSentence ) );
```

Comment: It return the original sentence back.

Comment: What do you see in the demo's output?

Comment: To make downvoter a looser I upvoted this answer. +1

Comment: Thanks, I did the same for you and classG

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in code, one way of doing it is with

```
(?:\s|^)(\S)
```

It matches a non white space character (`\S`) preceded by a white space OR beginning of string (`\s|^`), capturing the non white space character to capture group 1.

```js
var sentence  = 'Hello World\n'+
                'گروه جوانان خلاق',
    re        = /(?:\s|^)(\S)/g,
    result = '';
    
while( m = re.exec(sentence) )
{
  result += m[1];
};

console.log( result );
```

Comment: LOL! Is there a bot downvoting... ? Got -1 about a second after posting :D

Comment: Seems to be the case today!

Comment: To make downvoter a looser I upvoted this answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use a character range from `آ` to `ی` along with `a-z` since a word boundary in JS doesn't recognize multibyte letters while in most flavors it does.

```js
console.log(
  "سلام حالت چطوره؟".match(/( |^)[آ-یa-z](?=[آ-یa-z])/gi).map(x => x.trim()).join('')
)

console.log(
  "این یک test است".match(/( |^)[آ-یa-z](?=[آ-یa-z])/gi).map(x => x.trim()).join('')
)
```

Breakdown:

- `(?: |^)` Match a space or beginning of input string
- `[آ-ی]` Match a character from Farsi
- `(?=` Start a positive lookahead

  - `[آ-ی]` If followed by another Farsi character
- `)` End of positive lookahead

Note: character range from آ to ی has more than Farsi alphabets in it (some Arabic letters too) for a precise match (I doubt if you use those letters anywhere though) use a solid character class:

```
[اآبپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعفقگکلمنوهی]
```

```js
console.log(
    "سلام دوست من".match(/( |^)[اآبپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعفقگکلمنوهیa-z](?=[اآبپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعفقگکلمنوهیa-z])/gi).map(x => x.trim()).join('')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can simulate a word boundary.

Probably relevant is you can simulate a word boundary by enabling an engines Unicode option and using properties `[\p{L}\p{N}_]` to define a word Then just do the math for left/right boundary's.

```
/(?:(?<![\p{L}\p{N}_])(?=[\p{L}\p{N}_])|(?<=[\p{L}\p{N}_])(?![\p{L}\p{N}_]))/gu
```

This is a Korean sample but is applicable for any Unicode.

https://regex101.com/r/Mjttej/1

```
(?:                           # Cluster start
   (?<! [\p{L}\p{N}_] )          # Lookbehind assertion for a char that is NOT a word
   (?= [\p{L}\p{N}_] )           # Lookahead assertion for a char that is IS a word
   
 |                              # or,
   
   (?<= [\p{L}\p{N}_] )          # Lookbehind assertion for a char that is IS a word
   (?! [\p{L}\p{N}_] )           # Lookahead assertion for a char that is NOT a word
                                 # -------
)                             # Cluster end
```