# Regex: Match same expression multiple times and return full string before expression

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a string looking like this:

```
 /a/b/entry/0/c/d/entry/0
```

I would like to match `/entry/0` with `/entry/[0-9]+`. For each occurrence
individually and return an array

```
 ["/a/b/entry/0/", "/a/b/entry/0/c/d/entry/0"]
```

for arbitrary number of occurrences of `/entry/[0-9]+` in the string.
Also note that i would like to keep the expression in the output string.

Is this possible using a single Regex expression and the `string.match` or `string.split` function in JavaScript?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew did JS regex engine got an update recently? last I remember lookbehinds were not supported

Comment: @rock321987 Only Chrome latest versions support infinite width lookbehinds. It is part of the ECMA 2018 standard. Lookbehinds are not supported by the majority of browsers yet. So, it is not that portable a feature yet.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok but lookbehinds didn't worked at all in JS regex.. not checked in chrome

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [`this`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-javascript.html) too says lookbehinds were not supported at all, lest the infinite lookbehind..

Comment: @rock321987 See https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md. and https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/javascript-whats-new-in-ecmascript-2018-es2018-17ede97f36d5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yup.. you are right.. this was a recent update.. i am out-dated.. :(

Comment: @rock321987 Have a look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793359/javascript-regex-to-get-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-sentence-persian-and/49793589#49793589) showing how to finally match all Unicode letters without XRegExp with this new ECMA2018 update... It is becoming really cool.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew awesome..i have become quite out-dated about the recent developments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` and `reduce` as well.

```
var input = "/a/b/entry/0/c/d/entry/0";
var output = input.split( /(?<=entry\/[0-9]+)/ )
                  .reduce( (a, c) => { 
                       a.push( (a[a.length - 1] || "") + c ); //push new item after appending c to last item in accumulator
                       return a; return accumulator
                  } ,[])//initialize accumulator
```

**Demo**

```js
var input = "/a/b/entry/0/c/d/entry/0";
var output = input.split(/(?<=entry\/[0-9]+)/)
  .reduce((a, c) => {
    a.push((a[a.length - 1] || "") + c); //push new item after appending c to last item in accumulator
    return a;
    return accumulator
  }, []) //initialize accumulator

console.log(output);
```

**Edit**

Use @Wiktor's suggestion to `match` and then `reduce`

```
var input = "/a/b/entry/0/c/d/entry/0";
var output = (input.match(/.*?\/entry\/\d+(?:\/|$)/g) || []) //check for null
                  .reduce( (a, c) => { 
                       a.push( (a[a.length - 1] || "") + c ); //push new item after appending c to last item in accumulator
                       return a; return accumulator
                  } ,[])//initialize accumulator
```

Comment: hmmm.. it's working here.. did JS regex engine got updated?

Comment: @rock321987 I think the issue is with negative lookbehind, not the positive one. Negative one will work on chrome, but not everywhere.

Comment: nopes.. it used to be with both.. even negative one is working on regex101.. also this article is still old if its [updated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).. quoting from source `Finally, flavors like JavaScript, std::regex, and Tcl do not support lookbehind at all, even though they do support lookahead.`

Comment: Not sure if followed what you mentioned...I have seen positive lookbehind working for quite some time now, while for negative lookbehind support has been thinner.

Comment: @gurvinder372 That means, you only use Chrome :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I develop only on chrome since most of internet users (i guess 65-70% of them) uses chrome.. but I use IE as well (company policy :()

Comment: Thanks, Chrome works, Firefox not ... is there a solution that works on most Browsers?

Comment: @user3142067 You can use Wiktor's regex to match and then use reduce on top of that (which I had shared)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew returns `[ "/a/b/entry/0/", "c/d/entry/0" ]` but should be `[ "/a/b/entry/0/", "/a/b/entry/0/c/d/entry/0" ]`

Comment: @user3142067 Use https://jsfiddle.net/xdqmd33c/. Although I am not sure you need exactly this, since there is only 1 test case. What is the expected output for `/a/b/entry/0/c/d/entry/0/e/f/entry/0`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  That would be `[ "/a/b/entry/0/", "/a/b/entry/0/c/d/entry/0" ,"/a/b/entry/0/c/d/entry/0/e/f/entry/0"]`

Comment: Cool, then use my regex and gurvinder372's `reduce`.

Comment: @gurvinder372 You may add my suggestion, I removed the comment from below the question.

Comment: @gurvinder372  `return accumulator` is not necessary right?

Comment: It is necessary if you are using curly braces `{}`. You can also use `(a.push( (a[a.length - 1] || "") + c ), a)` without `{}`