# Uppercase first letter of each word and handling latin characters

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am trying to uppercase the first letter of each word in a sentence.

In javascript, `\b` seems to be intended for that : it matches the beginning of a word.

This works with ascii characters :

```
static capitalize(str: string): string {
  return str.replace(new RegExp('\\b\\w', 'g'), (txt) => txt.toUpperCase());
}
```

This test passes :

```
expect(StringUtils.capitalize('jean-michel dupont')).toEqual('Jean-Michel Dupont');
```

**Problem** : when I use latin characters, the latin character and the next character are uppercased.

```js
StringUtils.capitalize('Fais de ta vie un rêve, et d\'un rêve, une réalité.')
```

`Fais De Ta Vie Un RÊVe, Et D'un RÊVe, Une RÉAlité. // Actual`

`Fais De Ta Vie Un Rêve, Et D'Un Rêve, Une Réalité. // Expected`

Is there an option to handle that ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793359/javascript-regex-to-get-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-sentence-persian-and/49793589#49793589

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use CSS instead of JavaScript? If so, have a look at the [`text-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) CSS attribute.

Example:

```html
<div style="text-transform: capitalize">Fais de ta vie un rêve, et d'un rêve, une réalité.</div>
```

Comment: Same as above, you missed the `u` -> `U` in `d'un rêve` should become `D'Un Rêve`.

Comment: I don’t actually know the rules about capitalization after an apostrophe in latin. However, in English, I don’t expect the following to be capitalized after the apostrophe: `Don't`, `Friend's`. There may be a definitive set of rules that you can implement yourself as a regular expression, but you will need to weigh up the cost/effort to do this yourself.

Comment: I don't want to do it myself, that's not my problem but OP requierement

Comment: FYI that's not Latin but French.

Comment: Do you spell `O'Connor` or `O'connor`?

Comment: @Soc this use case is very interesting. In `Don't` and  `Friend's`, it would not make sense to capitalize `s`. But In French, `Jean d'Ormesson` means `John from Ormesson` so it makes sense to capitalize the `O`. This means that I will not find a css rule that does exactly what I want because it is locale sensitive.

Comment: Thanks all for pointing out this out. In a perfect world, this and other libraries will be locale aware. I was hoping that this would be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `(?:^|\\s)` instead of `\b` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10590516/11541562)

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)\\w", "g"), txt => txt.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(capitalize("Fais de ta vie un rêve, et d'un rêve, une réalité."));
```

Comment: You missed the `u` -> `U` in `d'un rêve` should become `D'Un Rêve`

Comment: That's fine ! I slightly modified it in order to take `'` into account and it works ! (`new RegExp('(?:^|\\s|\')\\w', 'g')`)

Comment: `\b` is more than `(?:^|\s)` (as already stated in the linked answer).

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: What about `.`, `,` and `?`, just to name a few? These are all word boundaries.

Comment: @Jan True. Up to now, my best option is to list "reasonnable" boundaries. Something like `new RegExp('(?:^|\\s|[!,:;\\-\'\.\?"])\\w', 'g')`